# Active record query: how to group for an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to find a smart way to get some records.

I have these classes:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :section
  has_many :answers
  has_many :quiz_questions
  has_many :quizzes, through: :quiz_questions
  has_many :question_stats
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :quizzes, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :user_profile
  has_many :questions, through: :quizzes
  has_many :question_stats
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :quizzes
end

class QuestionStat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
end
```

If I query for

```
current_user.question_stats
```

I receive my objects

```
=> [#<QuestionStat id: 1, user_id: 2, question_id: 2, errors_count: 0, done_count: 0, done: false>,
 #<QuestionStat id: 6, user_id: 2, question_id: 39, errors_count: 0, done_count: 0, done: false>,
 #<QuestionStat id: 7, user_id: 2, question_id: 102, errors_count: 0, done_count: 0, done: false>,
 #<QuestionStat id: 8, user_id: 2, question_id: 96, errors_count: 0, done_count: 0, done: false>,
 #<QuestionStat id: 9, user_id: 2, question_id: 46, errors_count: 0, done_count: 0, done: false>,
 #<QuestionStat id: 10, user_id: 2, question_id: 119, errors_count: 0, done_count: 0, done: false>,
```

I need to group the stats for section, so I know for every section how many question a user has answered and how many error he has done.

Question_id belongs_to Question that belongs_to Section.

I try also to proceed in another way, starting from current_user.questions

If I query

```
current_user.questions
```

I obtains all the questions a user answer.

```
<Question id: 94, quiz_type: "base", image: nil, text: "Com'è chiamato l'insieme degli organi con i quali ...", section_id: 1>,
 #<Question id: 68, quiz_type: "base", image: nil, text: "Come viene denominata la parte di calpestio più ba...", section_id: 1>,
 #<Question id: 111, quiz_type: "base", image: nil, text: "Un'elica destrorsa:", section_id: 1>,
 #<Question id: 103, quiz_type: "base", image: nil, text: "Si ha cavitazione quando:", section_id: 1>
```

Of course

```
current_user.questions.first.questions_stats.first
```

return me the stat for the specific question related to the single user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to include `section_id` in question stats so that you could simply do

```
QuestionStat.where(section: 1, user_id: current_user.id)
```

The way you have your current associations/tables/columns, the query to get question stats by sector would be very messy and inefficient as far as I can perceive.

Comment: do you suggest another data modeling?

Comment: Just to simply have the `section_id` column that you currently have on `Question` model, also in `QuestionStat` model.